# JQuery Modal dialog without overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, overlay

I'm trying to show an "ajax loader dialog" that blocks the interface (modal) but has no overlay.

This is how I initialize the dialog:

```
  $("<div></div>").dialog({
         modal: true,
         dialogClass: "noOverlayDialog",
         autoOpen: false, //opened later
         ...
  });
```

I added the following CSS to hide the overlay :

```
.ui-dialog.noOverlayDialog + .ui-widget-overlay { opacity: 0 !important; }
```

However, when I call `dialog("open")` the overlay flashes then disappears, as if I had hidden it using Javascript. Same effect using `display:none;` or `visibility:hidden`.

To make sure it was the css removing the overlay and not something else, I removed the line of css and surely enough the overlay was now always visible.

Why is this happening? I thought static CSS should not have this kind of behavior and the overlay should be hidden immediately without a flash.

If I can't find an intuitive solution, perhaps an alternative would be to set modal option to false to prevent the overlay all together, and then write code to get the modal behavior. Either way, I need a working solution.

Comment: I think your best option might be to override the actual CSS properties themselves declared in the jQueryUI style sheet which does the overlay background. When I say override, I meant not to change the CSS itself but add properties in your working HTML and redeclare them.

Comment: Isn't that what I did? The thing is I don't need it to be global but only apply to specific dialogs which have the class `.noOverlayDialog` . If that doesn't change you suggestion, please answer (not comment) with an example and I will try it. Thanks

Comment: No because you're redefining instead of overriding the actual classes.

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean. An example would go a long way...

Comment: Please provide a jsFiddle

Comment: by the way currently dialogClass does not add the class to the overlay, and the overlay is outside of the container for the dialog. In fact even with the new appendTo option the overlay is still attached to document.body. This should be fixed in the one of the upcoming versions.

Answer (score 6):

I got it to work on jsFiddle.  [Try this link](http://jsfiddle.net/hb8yA/)

```
<div id="dialog">
    <h3>Here is the dialog content</h3>
    <p id="dialogContent"></p>
</div>
<button onclick="$('#dialog').dialog('open');">open</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            title: 'My dialog',
            dialogClass: "noOverlayDialog",
            autoOpen:false,
            modal: true,
            open: function(event,ui){
                $('.noOverlayDialog').next('div').css( {'opacity':0.0} );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This will not work if there are more than one dialog in the page (in particular, `$('.noOverlayDialog').next('div')` will not always select the overlay - only in this particular case it does). Also, you're setting the `opacity` to `0` on `open`, but never resetting it to its default value, so other dialogs that **do** want a visible overlay will not work. I've provided an alternative [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14656717/520779), but you might want to fix these issues in yours.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true.  My solution would only affect the dialog associated with the #dialog div.  Any other dialog's will work according to the options passed to them. This is a working solution on my app that has a total of 15 different dialogs.

Comment: At first I thought the same, but while poking with your fiddle I ran into [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hb8yA/6/). While the first dialog works ok, the second hides **itself** instead of the overlay... (tip: close it with the `Esc` key and the rest of the screen keeps working)

Answer (score 4):

The overlay used by jQuery has class`ui-widget-overlay`. So Include the below css rule in your css,

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);  /* IE8 and lower */
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lhwsq/

**Note:**

1. Make sure that this rule is included after jQuery css or any other plugin css.
2. This style will be applied to any dialogs in the same page.

To make it work on any specific dialog see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586175/297641

Answer (score 3):

One option would be creating an additional class `overlay-hidden` and adding it to the overlay when the dialog is [opened](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open), removing it again when it's [closed](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose). That will ensure other dialogs in the page (which may require a visible overlay) continue working properly:

```
open: function(event,ui){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').addClass('overlay-hidden');
},
beforeClose: function(event,ui){
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').removeClass('overlay-hidden');
}
```

The `overlay-hidden` class will override the `opacity` to `0`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587592/520779) by @Vega:

```
.overlay-hidden {
    opacity: 0.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);  /* IE8 and lower */
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hb8yA/5/) at jsFiddle (adapted from @ShadeTreeDeveloper's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586175/520779)).

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that what you are seeing is the overlay background image rendering briefly before the transparency effect (not supported in all browsers, by the way) is able to kick in.

```
.ui-widget-overlay { background: none !important; }
```

The above should work. As comments above have already stated, though, posted an example on your server or JSFiddle would allow a more specific diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers below worked for me but I did eventually find the solution.

It turns out the dialog is initially rendered inside a container called `.ui-effects-wrapper` with the overlay following the container not the dialog:

```
<div class="ui-effects-wrapper" ... >
     <div class="ui-dialog" .... >
     </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" ...> </div>
```

Therefore my selector `.ui-dialog.noOverlayDialog + .ui-widget-overlay` would only take effect after the effects container was removed. To solve the issue I needed to target both selectors:

```
.ui-dialog.noOverlayDialog + .ui-widget-overlay, 
.ui-effects-wrapper + .ui-widget-overlay {
      background: none !important;
      opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Note, the second selector is global.